# Numpy slicing multidimensional error produces unexpected result

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, shapes, numpy-slicing

I have a multidimensional array of this shape:

```
(2, 200, 2, 3, 3, 114)
```

I would like to extract a specific set of values from it using this command:

```
pab[0][:][0][0][0][i]
```

So basically I need each value iterated over the second dimension for fixes values in the first, third, fourth, and fifth. The last dimension is in a loop.

However, it appears my way of slicing and wanting to extract over the second dimension does not work properly. After some investigation I found out that the shape does not change as expected. It appears I did not understand it correctly:

```
>>> pab.shape
(2, 200, 2, 3, 3, 114)
>>> pab[0].shape
(200, 2, 3, 3, 114)
>>> pab[0][:].shape
(200, 2, 3, 3, 114)
>>> pab[0][:][0].shape
(2, 3, 3, 114)             # I would have expected to see (200, 3, 3, 114)
>>> pab[0][:][0][0].shape
(3, 3, 114)
```

I found some articles talking about multidimensional slicing but none of them explained this behavior or I misunderstood them.

If someone can explain why the shape of the array changes as shown and not as expected to `(200, 3, 3, 114)` and also what the proper way would be I would highly appreciate this! In the end I was trying to get an array of shape `(200, )`

Comment: Does this do what you want `pab[0,:,0,0,0,i]`?

Comment: Looks like it. At least in the console. Will check for the original code

Comment: You could also post the original code for further improvements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing `numpy` with `arr[i][j]...` works with all scalars, but not with slices.  `[:]` does nothing.  (Even with a list `[:]` just makes a copy.).  So you want to combine the indexes into one expression:

```
In [40]: arr = np.ones((2, 200, 2, 3, 3, 114),int)                           
In [41]: arr.shape                                                           
Out[41]: (2, 200, 2, 3, 3, 114)
In [42]: arr[0].shape                                                        
Out[42]: (200, 2, 3, 3, 114)
In [43]: arr[0,:,0,0].shape                                                  
Out[43]: (200, 3, 114)
In [44]: arr[0,:,0,0,0,3].shape                                              
Out[44]: (200,)
```

Putting a slice in the middle like this can produce unexpected results:

```
In [45]: arr[0,:,0,0,0,[1,2]].shape                                          
Out[45]: (2, 200)
In [47]: arr[0][:,0,0,0,[1,2]].shape                                         
Out[47]: (200, 2)
```

Here the size 200 slice has moved to the end.  This an awkward case of mixed basic and advanced indexing. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing